# Notifying me of the flags against my answer

Tags: feature-request, flagging

8 days after activity had stopped on the answer to my question, I got a comment suggesting that there was a flag attempting to delete my answer (!!). The feature request is for me to know when someone has flagged me. Is it possible already to turn on such a notification?

[image]

Comment: I am pretty sure that I have seen this before on either [mso](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) or [mse](https://meta.stackexchange.com). But I can't find it right now.

Comment: @MEE I've had a look at [meta.se], but didn't find it. It is possible that it has been deleted. I do wonder what the utility is for viewing those flags, though. In the case mentioned here, for example, the only useful information would be that someone thinks your answer is bad, but that is already said in the comments. I don't really see what useful information I would get when I know when my posts are flagged.